# C++ Floating point errors in a loop vs in a single expression

Tags: c++, floating-point, compiler-optimization

(Disclaimer: I understand that floats can't represent tenths precisely.)

I was messing around in C++ with single-precision floats (to test out rounding errors), and I came across this weird behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  // set number of sigdigs in output
  cout << setprecision(9);

  float singleA = 0.1 * 7.;
  float singleB = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1;
  float singleC = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    singleC += 0.1;
  }
  // ^ i expected that to be the same as
  // 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1

  cout << "multiplied:      " << singleA << endl;
  cout << "added in one go: " << singleB << endl;
  cout << "added in a loop: " << singleC << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
multiplied:      0.699999988
added in one go: 0.699999988
added in a loop: 0.700000048
```

I was wondering why adding 0.1 7 times in an expression results in a different result than adding 0.1 7 times in a loop. I'm both adding 0.1 7 times, so why does this happen? Does `singleB` get optimized using *floating decimal arithmetic?*

Comment: `0.1` has type `double`. So the first computation accumulates in double precision, the second in single precision (`float`). The second computation potentially also incurs additional rounding errors due to mixed-precision computation. Try changing the literal constant to `0.1f`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0.1` is a `double`, not a `float`. So when you add seven of them in an expression, the operations are carried out using double-precision arithmetic and then the final result is converted to single precision. In the loop, you discard the extra precision after each addition. Try it with `0.1f` and you’ll get identical results.

Comment: And here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6YzKT64sf) to confirm it

Comment: Re “Try it with `0.1f` and you’ll get identical results.”: Not necessarily. The C++ standard allows an implementation to evaluate floating-point expressions with more precision than the nominal type, until an assignment or cast is performed. So a compiler could add `float` values using `double` arithmetic and get differently rounded results than if each result were individually stored in a `float`.

Comment: And, in fact, on Intel hardware, floating-point math is typically done with 80-bit precision, larger than either `float` or `double`. This was a big problem when Java came up with the notion of "strict math", which required that `float` arithmetic be done with 32 bits of precision and `double` arithmetic with 64 bits. It absolutely killed performance on Intel hardware.